# How to setup proxy connection for each instance qwebview?

Tags: qt, proxy, connection, qwebview

How to setup proxy connection for each instance qwebview?

I read the documentation, but i dont found info about that, i found how to set proxy for all application.

Can anyone helps me?Thanks.Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `QWebView` has its own `QNetworkAccessManager` (accessible through `QWebView::page()` and `QWebPage::networkAccessManager()`) which itself has the 2 methods `setProxy` and `setProxyFactory`.